# Calling functions inside a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to find a way to call each function inside the function, thirdQues. I don't want them to be global, and keep receiving an unexpected indentation error when I show they are nested within thirdQues in the main. I also plan to nest thirdQues in functions around the same size as itself. Any help appreciated.

```
import time
def thirdQues(a = ("Questions_7.txt"), b = ("Questions_8.txt"), c = ("Questions_9.txt")):
        myName=("none")



        def intro3():
                Intro1 = open(Intro3.txt, "r")
                print(Intro1)

        def announce3(): 
                input()
                print('"TT(Announcing):.... BIENVIENDOS AL CORO CIRCUIT! HOY TENENMOS.....(Welcome to the Coro Circuit! Today we have.....)"')
                time.sleep(5)
                print('" El jefe..... El mysterio..... El campeón de peso pesado......(The boss....... The mysterious........ the heavy weight champion....."')
                time.sleep(5)
                print('"Senor........ Diego!"')
                time.sleep(3)
                print('(Crowd electrifies the arena in excitement)') 
                print('Diego:(Staring you down with a neutral experssion and arms crossed): \n "HMPH.... "')
                input() 


                print('"TT(Announcing): ANNNND.....HONING IN FROM SU CASA CUIDAD, (Their hometown)"')
                time.sleep(3)
                print('".....VEN EL UN.....(Comes the one.....)"')
                time.sleep(2)
                print('"........EL SOLO......(The ONLY.....)"')
                time.sleep(3)
                print('"........CON DOS GANADORS DESPUES SU CINTURON......(With 2 wins under their belt.....)"')
                time.sleep(3)
                print('".......El' +(myName)+ '!!!!') 
                input()


                print('(The same woman from the last matches is now holding a small Japanese flag and blowing kisses towards you.') 
                print('TT: VAMOS A EMPEZAR CORO CIRCUIT! (LET"S GO CORO CIRCUIT!)')
                input()
        #I wanted to have the print statements timed instead of reading the announcements from a file to add depth.
        def Preguntas3():       
                text_file = open(a, "r")
                wholefile = text_file.read()
                print(wholefile)

                ans = ''    
                ans = input()
                yes = []
                yup = []
                right = [] 
                print('TT: Eres Cierto? (Are you sure? Be sure to properly spell out your answer.) \n (TYPE Y OR N)')
                sure = ''
                sure = input()
                if sure == str('y' or 'Y'):
                        answer = ''
                        answer=str(ans)
                else:
                        print('"TT: Lo siento, could you say that again?"')

                        answer = input() 
                time.sleep(3)
                if answer == str('To win is to adapt.'): 
                        print('..... '+(myName)+ ' seals the first hit!')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT: Whoa, that is an outrageous uppercut!')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Diego:......(Gives you a dark look and retains his stance)')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT: Seems you cannot win without adaptation....') 
                        print('TT: Next question')
                        yes=['Si']

                else:
                        print('TT: And Diego swipes the stage with a gizalle punch!')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT: Estoy sin palabras!!! (I am speechless!)') 
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Diego:..... Eres loco.... (You are foolish.)')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT: Next Question!')

                input()

                text_file = open(b , "r")
                wholefile = text_file.read()
                print(wholefile)

                ans = ''    
                ans = input()
                correct = []
                print('TT: Eres Cierto? (Are you sure? Be sure to properly spell out your answer.) (FULL SENTENCES NEED PERIODS.) \n (TYPE Y OR N)')
                sure = ''
                sure = input()
                if sure == str('y' or 'Y'):
                        answer = ''
                        answer=str(ans)
                else:
                        print('"TT: Lo siento, could you say that again?"')

                        answer = input() 
                time.sleep(3)
                if answer == str('Believe in yourself.'): 
                        print('.....(Crowd goes rampid).... TT: '+(myName)+' tiene el fuego! (Has the fire!) ')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT: Gosh! What a spectacular Haymaker!')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Diego:.........(Looks away briefly)')
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print('TT: Next question')
                        yup=['Tu']

                else:
                        print('......(Crowd goes insane) TT: We have got a pull counter de Senor Diego!')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT: NO PUEDO MIRAR, NO PUEDO MIRAR! ( I cannot look! I cannot look!')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Diego:.......Eres un inutil....(....You suck....') 
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT: IT IS TIME FOR THE FINAL QUESTION OF THE CORO CIRCUIT!!!')
                        time.sleep(2)
                        print('(The Crowd is shuffling like fireworks!)') 
                        time.sleep(4)
                        input()

                        print('(Diego stares at you with the harshest eyes you have ever seen in your life.)')
                        print('(He retains his stance and looks as if he is about to parry)') 
                        print('(You swallow deeply intimadation and discover what you must do next...)')

                text_file = open(c, "r")
                wholefile = text_file.read()
                print(wholefile)

                ans = ''    
                ans = input()
                print('TT: Eres Cierto? (Are you sure? Be sure to properly spell out your answer.) \n (TYPE Y OR N)')
                sure = ''
                sure = input()
                if sure == str('y' or 'Y'):
                        answer = ''
                        answer=str(ans)
                else:
                        print('"TT: Lo siento, could you say that again?"')

                        answer = input() 
                time.sleep(3)
                if answer == str('As always'): 
                        print('And....'+(myName)+' GETS THE HIT!')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT:..........')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Diego:..........')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('(Crowd:.........!)')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Woman in the crowd: Anata o shinrai shite imasu!!(I believe in you!)') 
                        input()
                        right=['Ganas']

                else:
                        print('TT: Anddd: Diego GETS THE LAST HIT!!!!')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        print('TT:..........')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('(Crowd:.........!)')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Woman in the crowd:.......(She ducks her head in sadness.) ')
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print('Diego:.......Soy el mejor......(....I am the best.....) ')
                        input()

                print('(.........You have had enough of this and decide to charge him force with all you might. \n He does the same....)')
                input() 
                print('TT: AY DIAS MIA! (OH MY GOD!) THEY ARE GOING AT IT RANDOMLY NOW NON STOP!?!.... GONNA HAVE TO DECLARE THE WINNER IN.......') 
                time.sleep(2)

                advance = (yes + yup + right) 
                if advance == ['Si','Tu','Ganas'] or ['Si', 'Tu',] or ['Tu', 'Ganas'] or ['Si', 'Ganas'] :
                                print('TT:10')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:9')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:8')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:7')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:6')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:5')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:4')
                                time.sleep(2)
                                print('TT:3')
                                time.sleep(2)
                                print('TT:2')
                                time.sleep(4) 
                                print('......1')
                                time.sleep(1) 
                                print('TT: AND THE GANADOR(Winner) ISSSSSSSS,' , +(myName)+ '!' 'Congratulations! YOU HAVE WON THE CORO CIRCUIT!')
                                print('Diego:........ Anata wa jibun o shinjite...... (He bows down for you and then vanishes in thin air.)') 
                else:
                                print('TT:10')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:9')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:8')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:7')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:6')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:5')
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print('TT:4')
                                time.sleep(2)
                                print('TT:3')
                                time.sleep(2)
                                print('TT:2')
                                time.sleep(4) 
                                print('......1')
                                time.sleep(1) 
                                print('TT: AND THE GANADOR(Winner) ISSSSSSS, DIEGO! Congratulations!')
                                input()


##                                print('Ricka: Me das asco........\n(You disgust me...... \n(He lifts his arms and glares at the crowd)')
##                                input()
##                                print('Ricka: RICKAKAKKKKAKAKKAAKKAKKAKAKKKAAKA!')
##                                input()
##                                print('(...... you pass out, unable to bear with blows of your opponent.... \n Until you wake up from this nightmare.... \n ')
##                                input()
##                                print('(Reality sets in, it is only 2:30 AM and you ask yourself.....)')
####                playAgain = 'yes'
##                while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':
##                        firstQues()
##                        a = ("Questions1.txt")
##                        b = ("Questions_2.txt")
##                        c = ("Questions_3.txt")
##                print('Do you want to go back to bed and finish this dream? \n (TYES YES OR Y) Or do you want to wake up and start your miserable day? \n (TYPE NO OR N)')
##                playAgain=input()
##              
def main():
        thirdQues(a = "Questions_7.txt",  b = "Questions_8.txt" ,c = "Questions_9.txt")
                intro3()
                announce3()
                Preguntas3()
main()
```

Comment: Your not receiving an error for trying to nest functions; That is syntactically valid. Your **indention**, is  the reason our getting an error. It's way off.

Comment: My indentation in the main or in the entire program?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you are encountering. Don't just dump a wall of code. Also, why do you put your strings in parentheses? e.g. `myName=("none")`?

Comment: Your indentation is definitely off in `main`. Regardless, you are calling `intro3`, `announce3`, and `Preguntas3` in the scope of `main`, but they do not exist outside the scope of `thirdQues`. Return them from `thirdQues` and assign them to something in-scope in `main`, then call them.

Comment: @RickBould the latter.

Comment: Sorry, still new to this site, and I use the "" and '' interchangably for strings.

Comment: When I return them, I type return and then the name of the function after the function is done right? (E.g. return Preguntas3 in indentation with this function). Or should it be done like return(intro3,announce3,Preguntas3) in indentation with thirdQues?

Comment: And I don't see how my identation is off......

Comment: No, you return the three as a tuple at the end. `return` stops the execution of your function, and nothing after it runs.

Comment: I'm confused. Why define a function inside another function definition? Your code would look much cleaner if you didn't keep using nested definitions. I can't understand what you're code is doing because there's so much of it.

Comment: @RickBould Python indentation is **four** spaces. You are using **eight** everywhere indentation is called for. Stop using tabs, or use an editor that automatically converts tabs to spaces, or just hammer out four spaces. But please do take a look at how regular Python programs are formatted.

Answer (score 0):

This indentation is wrong:

```
def main():
        thirdQues(a = "Questions_7.txt",  b = "Questions_8.txt" ,c = "Questions_9.txt")
                intro3()
```

You cannot indent `intro3()` here.

Besides that, use 4 spaces for indentation, rather than 8. Both are syntactically valid, but 4 spaces are always used. It just looks better and everyone is used to that.